# C# WebAPI not serializing dynamic properties correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I am creating a new C# OData4 Web API with a class named `Call` that has dynamic properties, which OData 4 allows via "Open Types". I believe I've set everything up and configured it correctly but the serialized response does not include the dynamic properties.

Did I configure something wrong?

```
public partial class Call 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, object> DynamicProperties { get; }
}
```

---

```
public class CallController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Call> GetCall([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        return _context.Call.GetAll();
    }
}
```

---

```
public static partial class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        AllowUriOperations(config);

        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.ComplexType<Call>();
        var model = builder.GetEdmModel();

        config.MapODataServiceRoute(RoutePrefix.OData4, RoutePrefix.OData4, model);    
    }

    private static void AllowUriOperations(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Count();
        config.Filter();
        config.OrderBy();
        config.Expand();
        config.Select();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value in a key pair is `null` the property is simply not serialized. I was expecting it to be serialized to

> "key" : null

**Here are some additional examples**

```
DynamicProperties.Add("somekey", 1);
```

> "somekey" : 1

---

```
DynamicProperties.Add("somekey", "1");
```

> "somekey" : "1"

---

```
DynamicProperties.Add("somekey", null);
```

> 

Answer (score 1):

You can enable serialization of null valued dynamic properties in OData open types by adding the following line (in my code in WebApiConfig.cs in method Register(HttpConfiguration config))

```
    config.Properties.AddOrUpdate("System.Web.OData.NullDynamicPropertyKey", val=>true, (oldVal,newVal)=>true);
```

Then my dynamic properties with nulls start to serialize.

Answer (score 1):

Or `configuration.SetSerializeNullDynamicProperty(true);` can be used, which is more cleaner and self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in your metadata, on the type `Call` do you have `OpenType="true"`? If not, try making it an `EntitySet` changing this line:

```
builder.ComplexType<Call>();
```

to this

```
builder.EntitySet<Call>("Calls");
```

If you do have `OpenType="true"` in your metadata, check that you definitely have some entries in your `DynamicProperties` collection

Comment: I am debugging through can confirm that are properties in the dictionary. I have tried both options on the builder, but neither works. The class is simply a class, it's not layed out in XML, so I'm not sure where I could set the OpenType=true. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It should appear in the metadata which would be at a url like http://localhost/$metadata

Comment: I get an error page when I try that, regardless, where would I set the metadata? I don't understand where that data comes from.

Comment: The metadata is a document that defines how you have setup your system, it will be created automatically by the system. What url do you use to access the system with?

Comment: localhost:11011, I tired the URL with the correct port

Comment: What does the url to retrieve Calls look like?

Comment: http://localhost:11011/odata/Call(1), answering that made me realize I didn't put /odata/ when I tried the metadata url before. I tried again and got it. Call does have OpenType set to true.